# How to prevent NHibernate SqlDateTime overflow when querying the database without using an IUserType?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Is it possible to prevent this exception when doing an NHibernate Linq query like the following:

```
var dateFilter = DateTime.Parse("1500-01-01");
return _session.Query<Log>().Where(l => l.Date > dateFilter).ToList();
```

Result:
`SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

I'd like to set the date to the minimum supported date value. I'm already using an Interceptor to do this when inserting and updating the database but I'm looking for a solution to fix Select queries.

```
public class DataInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
    {
        public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, object id, object[] currentState, object[] previousState, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
        {
            DateTimeMinValueToNull(currentState, types);
            return base.OnFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);
        }

        public override bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
        {
            DateTimeMinValueToNull(state, types);
            return base.OnSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
        }


        // Prevents the application from crashing when an object's DateTime value is lower than the SQL datetime min value
        private void DateTimeMinValueToNull(object[] state, IType[] types)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
            {
                if (types[i].ReturnedClass == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    var value = (DateTime?)state[i];
                    if (value.HasValue && value.Value < (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue)
                    {
                        state[i] = (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use another type instead of DateTime: [Date and Time data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without using an IUserType

Is this restriction only to avoid changing your mappings?

As in NHibernate 5.2 you can register your custom type as default for all `DateTime` properties:

```
//Somewhere before SessionFactory is created
TypeFactory.RegisterType(typeof(DateTime), new YourCustomDateTime(), new[] {"DateTime"});
```

And with this solution you don't need your current Interceptor.

Comment: Yes it was to avoid changing all mappings. I dit not know this. We'll have to upgrade to version 5.2 but we'll test this out.

Answer (score 1):

Which NHibernate version are you using?

With version 5.0.0, there was a breaking change regarding this behaviour (https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/5.1.5/releasenotes.txt):

> - The Date NHibernate type will no more replace by null values below its base value (which was year 1753). **Its base value is now
>     DateTime.MinValue.** Its configuration parameter is obsolete.

Comment: We are using version 4.0.